# How to post-process multiple datasets while reading new data and updating a graph

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following situation:

1. Datasets are generated by an external device, at varying intervals (between 0.1s and 90s). The code sleeps between acquisitions.
2. Each dataset needs to be post-processed (which is CPU-bound, single-threaded and requires 10s to 20s). Post-processing should not block (1).
3. Acquisition and post-processing should work asynchronously and whenever one dataset is done, I want to update a pyplot graph in a Jupyter notebook (currently using ipython widgets), with the data from the post-processing. The plotting should also not block (1).

Doing (1) and (2) serially is easy to do: I acquire all datasets, storing it in a list, then process each item, then display.

I don't know how to set this up in a parallel way and how to start. Do I use callback functions? Do callbacks work across processes? How do I set up the correct amount of processes (acquisition in one, processing and plotting the rest for each core). Can all processes modify the same list of all datasets? Is there a better data structure to use? Can it be done in Python?

Comment: Why should acquisition and post-processing work synchronously. Just imagine conceptually the acquirer receives the next dataset and puts it on an "input queue" of datasets to be processed and goes back to acquire the next dataset. A separate process (or multiple processes) reads these datasets from the input queue and performs the post processing and when done puts the result (whatever that is) on a second "plotting queue" where the plotting process is in a loop reading from the plotting queue for the next piece it has to plot. This is all asynchronous. What's wrong with this?

Comment: It's a typo, sorry. What you're saying is exactly what I try to do, but I don't know how to approach it in Python

Comment: Write two/three programs. It's almost always the correct approach to have each thing to be responsible for one thing and one thing only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general outline of the classes you need and how you put them together along the idea of (more or less) what I described in my comment. There are other approaches, but I think this is the easiest to understand. There are also more "industrial strength" products that implement message queueing but with even steeper learning curves.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count


def acquirer_process(post_process_queue):
    while True:
        # get next file and put in on the post processing queue
        info_about_file_just_acquired = acquire_next_file()
        post_process_queue.put(info_about_file_just_acquired)

def post_process_process(post_process_queue, plotting_queue):
    while True:
        info_about_file_just_acquired = post_process_queue.get()
        # post process this file:
        info_about_post_processed_file = post_process(info_about_file_just_acquired)
        plotting_queue.put(info_about_post_processed_file)

def plotting_process(plotting_queue):
    while True:
        # Get plotting info for next post-processed file:
        info_about_post_processed_file = plotting_queue.get()
        # Plot it:
        plot(info_about_post_processed_file)

def main():
    """
    The main program.
    """
    n_processors = cpu_count()
    # We need one acquirer process
    # We need one plotting process since the assumption is
    # that only a single process (thread) can be plotting at a time
    # That leaves n_processors - 2 free to work in parallel post processing acquired files:
    post_process_queue = Queue()
    plotting_queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    # All these processes that follow are "daemon" processes and will automatically
    # terminate when the main process terminates:
    processes.append(Process(target=acquirer_process, args=(post_process_queue,), daemon=True))
    processes.append(Process(target=plotting_process, args=(plotting_queue,), daemon=True))
    for _ in range(n_processors - 2):
        processes.append(Process(target=post_process_process, args=(post_process_queue, plotting_queue), daemon=True))
    # Start the processes:
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # Pause the main process:
    input('Hit enter to terminate:')

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed from the documentation that Queue only works with threads, not with processes. Do you know if they copy the data or if the data is shared?

Comment: No, no, no! There is a `threading.Queue` that works with threads and a `multiprocessing.Queue` that works with processes and it is the latter that I have used. The data is copied in the sense that when a call to `Queue.put` is made and then retrieved with `Queue.get` the data has been serialized/deserialized from one address space to another using the `pickle` module. So you can't just put any arbitrary data to a queue; it must be serializable using `pickle`.

Comment: I see. Thank you again! I guess I would have to use SharedMemory to avoid pickling?

Comment: Does pickling needs avoiding? But then you have not specified enough details about your application for me to know one way or another. Or create custom-tailored *managed objects* like the built-in ones, for example `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`. The return value from this call is a *proxy* object that can be passed directly to processes. The actual dictionary implementation resides in a processes that is started by class `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager`. A method call made on the proxy dictionary reference results in a remote method call via a socket so performance can be an issue.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into those. Thank you so much once more! I have experience with C, but limited experience with Python – the concepts don't really translate well, since C is so low-level (e.g. mutex locked events for when data has been acquired, and a data array that every process can access )

Comment: Python has shared memory arrays, too, with and without locking. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=array#multiprocessing.Array), for example.